# Get last value of Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to get the last value of the excel sheet. An excel sheet having almost 100+ columns and I need its net total, the last figure of the report. I have attached the image and also highlighted the value I need.

[image: Click for Image.]

Answer (score 0):

If you fill row 16 continuously (= no gaps), then you can use these formulas:

`=OFFSET(A16,0,COUNTA(16:16)-2)`
`=OFFSET(A16,0,COUNTA(16:16)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

This formula will find the last non-blank cell in row 18, even if there are blanks:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(18:18))),18:18)
```

From your screenshot, it looks like you actually need *two* values. In that case, this will return the value immediately to the left of the last value in row 18.

```
=INDEX(18:18,1,LOOKUP(2,1/NOT(ISBLANK(18:18)),COLUMN(18:18))-1)
```

This second formula also works even if there are blanks but it returns *whatever* is in the cell to the left of the last cell, even if that cell is blank.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I don't know the last column and row name or number. I don't have exactly sure either the last row is 18, 19 or 41, and column. It all depends on sales volume. I have 50+ sheets and I need the last cell (Grand Total) data.

Comment: @bilal If you're sure it will always be in one of 3 rows, we *could* make one very long formula for each sheet. If your comfortable using VBA, we would write a relatively simple macro to loop through each sheet, find the last non-blank cell in the last non-blank row, and create a summary sheet showing all the data. Your original question was about a single sheet, though.